# Passing props through in Render function

Tags: properties, reactjs, jsonp, render

Any idea why I can log out the 'conditions' variable but cannot pass it through as a property in the render method? It is always undefined - "cannot read property 'conditions' of undefined".

Code below.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import Square from '../components/square.jsx';
import Circle from '../components/circle.jsx';
import Weather from '../components/weather.jsx';

var conditions = [];
$.ajax({
    url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/forecast10day/q/England/London.json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        conditions = parsed_json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday;
        console.log(conditions[1].conditions);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>Hello React!!!</h1>
        <SquareComp />
        <Square />
        <Circle width={100} height={100}/>
        <Weather cityName={'London'} weatherConditions={conditions[1].conditions} />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('rootNode')

);
```

If I pre-fill the var all is well, so I'm guessing it's not receiving data before render is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is that you need to add state for react to know when to refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous. Immediately after calling it, it proceeds to calling `ReactDOM.render`, and, at this point `conditions` is still an empty array. You should render your components only after the Ajax call is finished loading the results sent from the server.

Try the following:

```
function renderConditions (conditions, domElement){
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello React!!!</h1>
            <SquareComp />
            <Square />
            <Circle width={100} height={100}/>
            <Weather cityName={'London'} weatherConditions={conditions[1].conditions} />
        </div>,
        domElement
    );
}
```

Define a function that render the data given as parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/forecast10day/q/England/London.json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        conditions = parsed_json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday;
        renderConditions(conditions, document.getElementById('rootNode'));
    }
});
```

Call the function `renderConditions` passing the appropriate parameters in the ajax success callback function.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I'm now going to go and research states so that if the AJAX fails, the entire thing won't :) - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is always asynchronous, so there's just no chance React will render with a meaningful 'conditions' array. Keeping your current architecture (which is fine), just move the render after the 'conditions' assignement in the ajax callback, or if you need to render the initial, empty state too move the render code inside a function and call it in both places.